# How to make a sticky sidebar in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a sticky sidebar like this one, cpmta.org, but with Bootstrap? I am having a hard time trying to do this...

Comment: It's already there in Bootstrap called affix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's already there in Bootstrap and it is called Bootstrap Affix. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myNav").affix({
        offset: { 
            bottom: 195 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And you can add the `data-spy` as well:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="195">
    <li class="active"><a href="#one">Section One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Section Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Section Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

For more information, kindly follow the instructions from:

- [Creating Pinned Element with Bootstrap](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-affix.php)
- [Understanding Bootstrap’s Affix and ScrollSpy plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/)