# How to use CSS position sticky to keep a sidebar visible with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a two columns layout like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 content"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    </div>
 </div>
```

If I set the `position:sticky` to the sidebar column, I get the sticky behaviour of the sidebar: https://codepen.io/marcanuy/pen/YWYZEp

CSS:

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 content"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 sticky">
    </div>
 </div>
```

But when I set the `sticky` property **only** to the **menu** that is located in the sidebar, so the *related articles* section scrolls normally and gets the *sticky* behaviour with the *menu div*, it doesn't work:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 content"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
       <div class="menu sticky">
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the screencast of the first example scrolling the whole sidebar with a sticky behaviour, and then changing the sticky property to the menu that doesn't work:

[image]

Bootstrap 4 [recommends](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components) the **sticky** property as the dropped support for the Affix jQuery plugin:

> Dropped the Affix jQuery plugin. We recommend using a position: sticky polyfill instead.

I have tested it in:

- Firefox 47.0 with `css.sticky.enabled=“true”` under `about:config`
- Chrome 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) with `experimental Web Platform features` enabled in `chrome://flags`

(This is not a duplicate of [How to make a sticky sidebar in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37645566/1165509) because that one is using BS affix)

Comment: Are you trying something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NAXgXQ

Comment: @NagaSaiA No, I want the _sticky_ effect described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position Instead of the letters, the sidebar should start with a relative position and then change to a fixed one.

Comment: so no jQuery or javascript?

Comment: @Giri No javascript, only with native browser `position:sticky` support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved enabling `flexbox`. After raising an issue in Bootstrap's [Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20307#issuecomment-233069019) repository I got an answer by a Bootstrap [member](https://github.com/cvrebert):

> The .col-xs-4 isn't as tall as the .col-xs-8, so there's basically no
>   space for the Menu to "float" within when the stickiness kicks in.
>   Make the .col-xs-4 taller and things work fine:
>   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXzoNJ If you enable the Flexbox version
>   of our grid system (via $enable-flex: true;), you get automatic
>   equal-height columns for free, which comes in handy in your case.

Answer (score 16):

In the stable **Bootstrap 4.0.0** release, this is done using the `sticky-top` class...

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/QJogUAHIyg/bootstrap-4-sticky-sidebar)

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
        ...
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="sticky-top">
                <h4>Sticky menu</h4>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This works even in the height of the header/navbar, content, and footer are dynamic/unknown.

https://codeply.com/go/QJogUAHIyg

Comment: Sticky-top on the sidebar works, but doesn't seem to account for what happens if the sidebar contents are taller than the viewport. In this scenario, the sidebar contents cannot be scrolled in to visibility until the user scrolls to the end of the "content" content.

Answer (score 1):

[Polyfill explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5)

You need to include the JS polyfill in order to use it.  The polyfills recommended by the link on the Bootstrap page are

- https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill
- https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

Here is an updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBpNRk

I included the required polyfill (I used stickyfill) and called it with

```
var stickyElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky');

for (var i = stickyElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Stickyfill.add(stickyElements[i]);
}
```

The library suggested you use this for your css

```
.sticky {
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
}
.sticky:before,
.sticky:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

and finally you had the `div` order mixed up.  You need to put the `div` with the sticky class outside of an entire row so I filled up the rest of the row with another `<div class="col-xs-6"></div>` that is empty.

Comment: I am using browsers that supports `position:sticky` natively as specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @wrldbt works up to bootstrap 4 alpha 5, but in alpha 6 the `-xs` infix has been dropped and the grid have been rewritten.

I put something together, a bit cleaner, working with current version of bootstrap & also included a sticky footer using flexbox.

https://codepen.io/cornex/pen/MJOOeb