# How to create a fixed sidebar layout with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm trying to create a layout like the screenshot using Bootstrap 4 but I'm having some problems with making the sidebar fixed and achieving this layout at the same time.

Going with a basic example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-m-4" id="sticky-sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-m-8" id="main">
      Main Area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's possible to get this layout but things get tricky once I declare:

```
.sidebar {
position: fixed // or absolute
}
```

Once I make the sidebar sticky, the *main* div starts appearing **behind** the sidebar instead of next to it. Of course it's possible to declare some margin and push it back to it's original position but it makes things complicated for responsiveness.

I feel like I'm missing something, I read the Bootstrap 4 documentation but I couldn't find a simple way to achieve this layout.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

***Updated 2020***

Here's an updated answer for the latest **Bootstrap 4.0.0**. This version has classes that will help you create a **sticky** or **fixed sidebar** without the extra CSS....

Use `sticky-top`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-3">
        <div class="col-3 order-2" id="sticky-sidebar">
            <div class="sticky-top">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <h1>Main Area</h1>
            ...   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://codeply.com/go/O9GMYBer4l

***or***, use `position-fixed`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 px-1 bg-dark position-fixed" id="sticky-sidebar">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col offset-3" id="main">
            <h1>Main Area</h1>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://codeply.com/p/0Co95QlZsH

**Also see:**
[Fixed and scrollable column in Bootstrap 4 flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281623/fixed-and-scrollable-column-in-bootstrap-4-flexbox/49282391)
[Bootstrap col fixed position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972833/bootstrap-col-fixed-position/48974617#48974617)
[How to use CSS position sticky to keep a sidebar visible with Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382043/how-to-use-css-position-sticky-to-keep-a-sidebar-visible-with-bootstrap-4/49111934)
[Create a responsive navbar sidebar "drawer" in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996084/create-a-responsive-navbar-sidebar-drawer-in-bootstrap-4/48996139)

Comment: nice solution, but we need to wait for fully support 'sticky' in browsers

Comment: Re: #1 - what if the height of the sidebar contents is taller that the viewport? With this method, the bottom-most content of the sidebar is hidden off viewport until the user reaches the bottom of the Main Area content.  Sidebar should allow scrolling to reveal all vertical content.

Comment: Can I create another container in the right column or that would be considered a bad practice?

Comment: The problem with this solution is it applies well only if there are no headers, or else the header will obscure the sidebar since `sticky-top` only "position[s] an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge, but only after you scroll past it." https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/

Comment: @BrianTag this is outside the scope of the original question, but I don't understand the issue: https://www.codeply.com/go/YThL9dPewG

Comment: Thank you very much. The first solution works like a charm.

Comment: This sidebar is not responsive, what if we need to place the sidebar in order 2 in the layout? (when entering mobile sizes)

Answer (score 10):

something like this?

```css
#sticky-sidebar {
position:fixed;
max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="sticky-sidebar">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="main">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: If you add some lorem ipsum to your sidebar content you can see that my initial problem gets recreated in this snippet. Because we're declaring a fixed position, sidebar stops respecting the grid system.

Comment: I edited the code an added `max-width: 20%` to the sidebar

Comment: Yes, declaring max-width to containers fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the new Bootstrap 4 alpha 6+ you'll need to remove the "xs-" prefix from the column sizes.

Comment: The trick of nesting a col-12 inside the col-4 worked really well for me

Comment: This no longer works for 4.0 and doesn't follow Bootstrap conventions.

Answer (score 5):

I used this in my code:

```
<div class="sticky-top h-100">
    <nav id="sidebar" class="vh-100">
        ....
```

this cause your sidebar height become 100% and fixed at top.

Comment: Works also in Bootstrap 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the J.S. to fix a sidebar menu. I've tried a lot of solutions with CSS but it's the simplest way to solve it, just add J.S. adding and removing a native BootStrap class: "position-fixed".

The J.S.:

```
var lateral = false;
function fixar() {

            var element, name, arr;
            element = document.getElementById("minhasidebar");

            if (lateral) {
                element.className = element.className.replace(
                        /\bposition-fixed\b/g, "");
                lateral = false;
            } else {

                name = "position-fixed";
                arr = element.className.split(" ");
                if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
                    element.className += " " + name;
                }
                lateral = true;
            }

        }
```

The HTML:

Sidebar:

```
<aside>
        <nav class="sidebar ">
             <div id="minhasidebar">
                 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" 
                     th:href="@{/hoje/inicial}"> <i class="oi oi-clipboard"></i> 
                     <span>Hoje</span>
                     </a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
        </nav>            
</aside>
```

Answer (score -5):

My version:

```css
div#dashmain { margin-left:150px; }
div#dashside {position:fixed; width:150px; height:100%; }
```

```html
<div id="dashside"></div>
<div id="dashmain">                        
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Content</div>
        </div>            
    </div>        
</div>
```