# How to left column fixed and right scrollable in Bootstrap 4, responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sticky, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 4, Bootstrap 4 and trying to implement a fixed scrollable right div and a fixed left div. It should very similar to what [Trulia](https://www.trulia.com) has.

Bootstrap dropped the Affix jQuery plugin in version 4 so this method is not valid anymore, they recommend to use position: sticky, but I cant get it to work.

Please help!

index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="left-container">
        <div class="search-property">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="right-container">
        <app-home-right></app-home-right>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
#left-container {
  height: 100%;

  position: fixed;
  width: inherit; 
}

#right-container {
  position: absolute;
}

.search-property {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if you simply want a layout with 1 fixed side, or for the side to be fixed until it reaches the footer (like Trulia). Here's a simple layout with fixed left side (Split 50 50).

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

To make the side fixed (or sticky) only at a specific point, `position:sticky` doesn't work very well across all browsers. I'd use a plugin or polyfill as explained here: [How to use CSS position sticky to keep a sidebar visible with Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382043/how-to-use-css-position-sticky-to-keep-a-sidebar-visible-with-bootstrap-4)

https://codeply.com/go/IuOp3nvCpy

[image]

**Update Bootstrap 4.0.0** - The `fixed-top` class is now in Bootstrap which can be used on the left side column to remove the extra css that was required for `position:fixed`.

**Update Bootstrap 4.1** - The `h-100` class is now available which eliminates the extra CSS that was needed for `height:100%`: https://codeply.com/go/ySC2l4xcEi

**Responsive** - As mentioned in the comments, a media query can be used to make the layout responsive: https://codeply.com/go/pqzJB4thBY

---

Related:

[Bootstrap col fixed position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972833/bootstrap-col-fixed-position/48974617)

[How to create a fixed sidebar layout with Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497288/how-to-create-a-fixed-sidebar-layout-with-bootstrap-4/49436717#49436717)

Comment: I will have a search form on left and I need to have this responsive (be on top of the right div on mobile). How do I do that?

Comment: Use the grid classes on the columns and a media query to only apply the fixed at larger widths like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/pqzJB4thBY

Comment: Fantastic response.