# Bootstrap 4 - Fixed column

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive, sticky

I'm using Bootstrap v. 4.0.0 and I have a two column (col-md-6 + col-md-6) layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 projects--snasphot-area">
        <!-- Many img here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 sticky-top projects--info-area">
        <!-- Text here -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The left column is very long, and can be visualized by scrolling down the page. I would like the right column to follow along with the scrolling, so that its contents are always readable. Thus, I have tried to add the Boostrap "[sticky-top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/)" class and also to assign "[align-self-start](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)", as suggested in a [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox)... But there's still no scrolling.

Comment: Please post the code that reproduces the issue in the question itself. **Future readers of this question** won't find it useful or helpful if the external link changes or becomes obsolete.

Comment: I don't know if you've previously used Bootstrap 3? They used to have a third-party JS plugin to achieve this, called 'Affix'. It's been dropped from 4 and in the migration part of the BS4 docs, they recommend applying "position: sticky;" or using 'ScrollPos-Styler'.

I'd suggest taking a look at ScrollPos-Styler - if you need a hand, come back and perhaps edit this question and I'll happily put a code example together if you need it.

Comment: The class "sticky-top" is just a shortcut to add a "position:sticky" - as suggested by the migration docs - and that's what was not  working... Anyway, I just went for position:fixed, with a few tinkering on z-indexing and media queries. Thank anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to left column fixed and right scrollable in Bootstrap 4, responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086159/how-to-left-column-fixed-and-right-scrollable-in-bootstrap-4-responsive)