# Bootstrap col fixed position

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

How can I fix Bootstrap col.

I tried like this but it is not working:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Content goes here...</div> 
    <div class="col-md-6" style=" position: fixed">Content goes here...</div> 
</div>
```

`fixed` position makes col as absolute position.

And  how can I disable a fixed position, when the page is scrolled down from top 400px.

Comment: 4.0  Bootstrap  version

Answer (score 0):

Use media query to only apply the fixed position above a specific screen width. For example 768px is the Bootstrap 4 `md` breakpoint:

CSS (`min-height` is optional):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .fixed-posi {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        min-height:100%;
        position:fixed;
    }
}
```

Then, use `fixed-posi` in the layout like this...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           Content goes here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 fixed-posi">Content goes here... (fixed position)
        </div>
   </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/751CygARyO

Similar question (fixed DIV on left): [How to left column fixed and right scrollable in Bootstrap 4, responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086159/how-to-left-column-fixed-and-right-scrollable-in-bootstrap-4-responsive)

Comment: but how fix this   <div class="col-md-7">Content goes here...</div> 
 <div class="col-md-3" style=" position: fixed">Content goes here...</div> 
 <div class="col-md-2" style=" position: fixed">Content goes here...</div>

Comment: That's not the original question. Edit the original question