# Bootstrap responsive sidebar menu to top navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

So I've been searching and searching for guidance in this with no avail.

Basically, I just want to have a sidebar, but when the screen gets small, aka smartphones screen size, it transforms into a navbar.

My HTML code for the sidebar is this:

```
<nav class="col-sm-3 ">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fixed-sidebar">
    <!-- <a href="index.html"><img id="home-logo" src="../media/logo-prueba.jpg" alt="Logo de Animanoir"></a>  -->
    <ul>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Animación</li>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Ilustración</li>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Interacción</li>
      <br>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Blog</li>
      <br>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada"><a href="acerca.html">Acerca</a></li>
      <li class="fuente-fjalla ul-personalizada">Contacto</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
#fixed-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 20%;
    color: white;
}
```

I have no idea how to get that into a navbar. All I know is how to make the navbar from start, but I don't want that! I don't want any of that fancy animated-overlay-multicolor-accordion-whatever things, please-

Thank you :)

Comment: post your css please

Comment: I'm not sure if the css `@media` property is what you're looking for or not. It lets you display different CSS depending on the size of the screen. For example, you could have a red background on a screen with a minimum width of 1080, and a blue background on a screen with a maximum width of 780. But, for further assistance, I need you to post your CSS code.

Comment: @Jonny I think there's no need; I don't have anything 'different' from a normal CSS to make it responsive (since I don't know).

Comment: @CelticTree Added the simple CSS for #fixed-sidebar

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Some of the classed have change for Bootstrap 5, but the concept is still the same. Here's an updated [Bootstrap 5 sidebar to navbar example](https://codeply.com/p/Nkp8O77PFS)

```css
/* this is needed to make the content scrollable on larger screens */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .h-sm-100 {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row vh-100 overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark d-flex sticky-top">
            <div class="d-flex flex-sm-column flex-row flex-grow-1 align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-sm-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5">B<span class="d-none d-sm-inline">rand</span></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-sm-column flex-row flex-nowrap flex-shrink-1 flex-sm-grow-0 flex-grow-1 mb-sm-auto mb-0 justify-content-center align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-house"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-speedometer2"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-table"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-sm-0 px-1" id="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-bootstrap"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-grid"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                            <i class="fs-5 bi-people"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="dropdown py-sm-4 mt-sm-auto ms-auto ms-sm-0 flex-shrink-1">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="28" height="28" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">Joe</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column h-sm-100">
            <main class="row overflow-auto">
                <div class="col pt-4">
                    <h3>Vertical Sidebar that switches to Horizontal Navbar</h3>
                    <p class="lead">An example multi-level sidebar with collasible menu items. The menu functions like an "accordion" where only a single menu is be open at a time.</p>
                    <hr />
                    <h3>More content...</h3>
                    <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
                    <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="row bg-light py-4 mt-auto">
                <div class="col"> Footer content here... </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

It could be done in Bootstrap 4 using the responsive grid columns. One column for the sidebar and one for the main content.

[Bootstrap 4 **Sidebar switch to Top Navbar** on mobile](https://www.codeply.com/go/Rgq96HykJ2/sidebar-that-changes-to-navbar)

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <aside class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0 bg-dark">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark flex-md-column flex-row align-items-start">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="flex-md-column flex-row navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        ..
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <main class="col">
            ..
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Alternate sidebar to top](https://www.codeply.com/go/kTmpqn61nq)
[Fixed sidebar to top](https://www.codeply.com/go/SCcAHh39Pa)

For the reverse (Top **Navbar that becomes a Sidebar**), can be done like [this example](https://www.codeply.com/go/b2fHkwPopV)

Comment: Hey, great solution. Where is wrapper defined? I can't find it on bootstrap4 documentation

Comment: Great start for a solution.   I find that the width of the navbar when vertical is proportional to the browser width, and the high, when horizontal is proportional to the height of the browser window.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Zim I may be wrong about this but when you use the bootstrap rows and columns then you can't make the sidebar "stick"
If you want the sidebar to scroll with the main content then I believe you have to use div tags and do a bit more customization unfortunately.
Take a look at this https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The alternate and fixed examples demonstrate a fixed sidebar with the grid.

Comment: This is fantastic, I've been trying to add a "collapsible" menu using the dropdown class but the standard navbar solution, when acting as a sidebar, will open a "separate" menu, instead of a collapsible one, as it's the usual when the navbar is on top. I guess the boostrap default won't support this out of the box.

Comment: Please take my upvote, and also tell me if I place all this code in my <body><section> and leave the <header> blank? or split them between the two for the navbar vs. the main content?

Comment: To make the sidebar sticky: add `overflow: auto; max-height: 100vh;` to `$("main.col")`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the sidebar have a fixed width? So that the width of the sidenav does not change along with the browser window width.

Answer (score 3):

**Big screen**:

[image: navigation side bar in big screen size]

**Small screen (Mobile)**

[image: sidebar in small mobile size screen]

if this is what you wanted this is code 
https://plnkr.co/edit/PCCJb9f7f93HT4OubLmM?p=preview

**CSS + HTML + JQUERY :**

```css
    
    @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
    body {
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      background: #fafafa;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1.7em;
      color: #999;
    }
    
    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      padding: 15px 10px;
      background: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .navbar-btn {
      box-shadow: none;
      outline: none !important;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .line {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
      margin: 40px 0;
    }
    /* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
    
    #sidebar {
      width: 250px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 999;
      background: #7386D5;
      color: #fff !important;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    #sidebar.active {
      margin-left: -250px;
    }
    
    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
      padding: 20px;
      background: #6d7fcc;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul.components {
      padding: 20px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul p {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li a {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      display: block;
      color:white;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
      color: #7386D5;
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    #sidebar ul li.active>a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
      color: #fff;
      background: #6d7fcc;
    }
    
    a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
    a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
      content: '\e259';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      font-size: 0.6em;
    }
    
    a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
      content: '\e260';
    }
    
    ul ul a {
      font-size: 0.9em !important;
      padding-left: 30px !important;
      background: #6d7fcc;
    }
    
    ul.CTAs {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    ul.CTAs a {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0.9em !important;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    a.download {
      background: #fff;
      color: #7386D5;
    }
    
    a.article,
    a.article:hover {
      background: #6d7fcc !important;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
    
    #content {
      width: calc(100% - 250px);
      padding: 40px;
      min-height: 100vh;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    #content.active {
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
      }
      #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      #content {
        width: 100%;
      }
      #content.active {
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
      }
      #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 3</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

</head>

<body>



  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>Header as you want </h3>
        </h3>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p>Dummy Heading</p>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#menu">Animación</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#menu">Ilustración</a>


        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#menu">Interacción</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Acerca</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">contacto</a>
        </li>


      </ul>


    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content Holder -->
    <div id="content">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>


    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

if this is what you want .

Comment: he asked for Bootstrap 4 but this is using Bootstrap 3 and looks a lot like  https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't a good solution for any reason, please let me know. It worked fine for me.

What I did is to hide the Sidebar and then make appear the navbar with *breakpoints*

```
@media screen and (max-width: 771px) {
    #fixed-sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    #navbar-superior {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming I understand how you're using these ids, one flaw this solution has is that now you must manage two navigation menus. So if a new link is added to one, it must be added to the other.