# is it possible to show a special navbar on a certain device and another one on smaller using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Hope you're all well.
I'll be fast and precise. Right now, I've make a custom navbar (the picture is below). But of course, this navbar need to be desactivated when the screen is too small to have it and shown a normal navbar at the top. Is it possible to do it using bootstrap ?

Picture of my actual custom navbar (on the left) :
[image]

Cordially

Comment: Post the code you've attempted. Do you mean [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472771/bootstrap-4-responsive-sidebar-menu-to-top-navbar/48477019#48477019)?

Comment: JP. Aulet anwsered to my question sir. Thank you anyway. But I still have a problem (you can find the code below). Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for responsive layout: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

In your case, this could show this sidebar on certain width (large devices) and hide it on others, like:

```
<div class='yourLargeNavbar'> ... </div>

<div class='yourSmallNavbar'> ... </div>
```

And then, with CSS:

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
    .yourLargeNavbar{
      display:none;
    }
    .yourSmallNavbar{
      display:block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767.98px) { 
        .yourLargeNavbar{
          display:block;
        }
        .yourSmallNavbar{
          display:none;
        }
    }
```

This way, when the screen size is less than 767px, the small navbar will appear and the large one disappear, and viceversa.

There are a lot of examples, and Bootstrap has their own `navbar` component that  works with a responsive way: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Edit: Check the code now:

```
<div class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample07" aria-controls="navbarsExample07" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </div>
```

You should change the class: `nav-toggler` to `navbar-toggle` and delete the "bs" in some data-params and change the button to div. Replace the piece of code for the one I posted and it should work.

Here: https://codepen.io/jpaulet/pen/xxEprGB

Comment: Hello, its working. But the collapse is not working... https://codepen.io/ismaelzem/pen/ExgommQ

Comment: I've tried the same bootstrap code but still still not working. I do have the 3 script as you can see in my codepen...

Comment: I edited your codepen to make it work and edited the answer, please check it.

Comment: I think you need to create a new codepin and give me the link because the code in my codepen is still not working :/

Comment: Check it now! ;)

Comment: Its working, thank you ! What was the problem ?