# Bootstrap sticky-top on sidebar column doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky sidebar on the right. The sidebar menu is inside a grid column. I'm using the `sticky-top` class as [shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382043/), but it still doesn't work.

Here's the code...

```
<div class="container min-vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 content pt-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="menu sticky-top p-3 bg-light">
                <h5 class="text-primary">Sticky menu</h5>
                <div class="nav flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-0">Menu 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-0">Menu 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-0">Menu 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codeply: https://codeply.com/go/xwYPD1B1tk

The `menu` div is the one I'd like to stick to the top as the user scrolls down.

Comment: yes, it's a very particular case, not easy to find ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Position sticky will not work if *any* of the parent containers of the sticky element use `overflow:hidden`. Removing the `overflow-hidden` class from the container allows the `sticky-top` to work.

```
<div class="container min-vh-100">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand">
        ..
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 content pt-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="menu sticky-top p-3 bg-light">
                <h5 class="text-primary">Sticky menu</h5>
                <div class="nav flex-column">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/9Nf6pOa7TN

Comment: The "sticky" is not working if menu is longer then browser view

Comment: @bron nothing can be done except giving the sidebar menu a defined height and adding overflow-auto so it scrolls